# Host WCF with external domain name

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, hosting

How can I find out what's wrong in hosting my wcf service?

Here is my service configurations:

[image]

[image]

When I remove my site url and put local host, I'm able to see my service. but I can't access that service from outside my network.

Comment: can you **ping** from outside?

Comment: Yes I'm able to ping my domain from outside and I want to map my service to that domain like mysite.com/myservice.svc. Then it is not working